# Cannot preview Github Pages site. What am I missing?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to locally preview a Github Pages Jekyll website.
This is the repository https://github.com/jacoping/jekyll-test and it works just fine on Github Pages: https://jacoping.github.io/jekyll-test/ .

I'm using https://pmarsceill.github.io/just-the-docs/ theme and as suggested in the docs I'm following this guide:
https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/testing-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll

I have Bundler and Jekyll installed. I cloned the repository locally and I think that the "publishing source" for my repository is the root directory of it. When I arrive to "3. Run bundle install" I get "Could not locate Gemfile".

I understand that for bundle to work I should have a Gemfile in the directory, but since the guide does not talks about it I feel like I'm missing something.

Thank you for helping me find a clue!